# Is it possible to refer to Array Resource Items directly in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

In code, it's easy to use the Resources class to get an instance of an XML typed array resource and traverse its items.  My question: is it possible to reference array resource items in XML itself as shown below

```
<resource>
<array name="items">
  <item>Item One</item>
  <item>Item Two</item>
  <item>Item Three</item>
</array>
<string name="itemThree">@array/items[2]</string>
</resource>
```

The format shown above does not work.  Does anyone know if that is possible using a different format?

Answer (score 1):

No, but I think the reverse works. Define your strings as string resources and refer to them as `@string/...` in the `<item>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would just define itemThree in Java:

```
String itemThree = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items)[2]
```

Ultimately, the XML gets inflated into Java objects, so it's not much difference IMO.